# Macro not working correctly when moved to a different folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have currently encountered a problem where my macros are out of sync after I changed the folder location. I have a macro that copies excel information to a word document template. When they are in my C:\ drive it runs smoothly with no error. Now I want to move it to a public server so my colleagues can use it as well and when I do so, some of the macros that used to work perfectly are offset by 1 or 2 spaces or not even putting the information in the right spot. When I transfer the documents back to my C:\ drive they work perfectly again. I am very confused on what the problem is so if any of you could help that'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub GageTest2()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim NumRows As Integer

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("P:\New Gage Lab Process\Gage Lab Form Template.docm")
'This opens Template

 Dim StrValue As String

For i = 2 To 6
'This populates the Gage ID

 objDoc.Activate

 StrValue = Cells(i + 1, 1)

 objWord.Selection.MoveDown
 objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue

    If StrValue = "" Then
    Exit For

    End If
 Next i

 For i = 2 To 6
'This populates the Gage Type
    objDoc.Activate

Set Rng = Range("A3:A7")
NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng)

StrValue = Cells(i + 1, 3)

If NumRows = 5 Then
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=5
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=-4
Else
'Do Nothing
End If

If NumRows = 4 Then
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=5
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=-4
Else
'Do Nothing
End If

If NumRows = 3 Then
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=6
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=-5
Else
'Do Nothing
End If

If NumRows = 2 Then
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=7
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=-6
Else
'Do Nothing
End If

If NumRows = 1 Then
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=8
    objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=StrValue
    objWord.Selection.MoveDown count:=-7
Else
'Do Nothing
End If

    If StrValue = "" Then
     Exit For

End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the code to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is lin 17 of your code ;-)

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that forgot to add my code.

Comment: is the P:// Drive a local or a netkworkdrive?

Comment: @Moosli The P:// Drive is a network drive so other people can use it.

Comment: does the problem ocure in the first loop or the second?

Comment: The second loop is where it starts OffSetting by 1, I have 4 other loops but if I can locate the problem in this one, I assume can use it for the other 4 as they are the same just pulling different information

Answer (score 0):

Without the Files you are using i would sugust an Error where you check if the sting is empty or in the Count function for the Rows.

For the if Statement you could try something like this.

```
If StrValue = "" or StrValue = vbNullString Then
     Exit For
End If
```

or there is an Error in the Count Method and you can try to use

```
NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Rng)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for the answer, weird enough I just put it in a Q:\ and it ended up working fine. Don't know what was wrong with P:\ but thanks again for your help!